# Custom Linux Timezone

Tags: windows, timezone, parted-magic, rdesktop

I believe rdesktop 1.7.1 is sending Linux timezones (For example "EST") to the Windows client I regularly connect to *(I am yet to find a way of seeing what Windows receives in the way of RDP settings in general, or just the timezone setting; Nor do I know how to monitor what rdesktop is sending to the Windows client. If anyone can increase my knowledge in either of these areas, please provide info/point me at something to read)*.

This seems to be causing an issue with Windows, as it doesn't match any of the timezones in the registry @ `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` (See below error *"Your current time zone is not recognized. Please select a valid time zone using the link below"*).

[image]

I don't have `zic` on my live distro (Parted Magic) and so was wondering if there is any other way of changing the time zone to display "Eastern Daylight Time" either system wide, or just what rdesktop sends?

Comment: AFAICT from reading the source, rdesktop only sends the UTC offset in number of minutes, so I suspect your issue is elsewhere. Try `TZ=UTC0 rdesktop...` to see if a 0-UTC offset timezone confuses Windows less.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TZ` environment variable for a single command. Here is an example for `rdesktop`:

```
TZ='America/Chicago' rdesktop 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: jordanm - If I `export TZ='America/Chicago'` and then `date` I get a time in "CDT". Are you saying that rdesktop will send "Central Daylight Time" (The entry for CDT in the Windows registry key referenced in my question) to Windows with this setting?

Comment: Please provide more detail. I cannot add that line to the rdesktop command.
How to get that issue fix? Thank you

Comment: @frank why can't you?